# Why My Jsp page not calling when I am using href link?

Tags: jquery, spring

I am working on spring in my Project .I have href link when the link is clicked i want to call my post method I am doing like below

```
<a href="javascript:getUserProfileData('1','2')">Click Here</a> 

function getUserProfileData(userIds,userName){
   alert("hi");
   $.post("/gDirectory/bhanutest.htm",{ userIds: userIds, userName: userName } );     
}
```

**MyController**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/gDirectory/bhanutest.htm" ,method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String bhanuTest(@RequestParam String userIds,String userName,Model model) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("The userId is..:"+userId);
    return "bhanuTest";
}
```

**bhanuTest.jsp**

calling my jsp page

every thing working fine but my jsp page not calling...any one help me

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: no error that jsp not calling

Comment: Post spring configuration file.

Comment: post your web.xml code here.

Comment: @RequestParam("userIds") String userIds, @RequestParam("userName") String userName,Model model -- Pass parameters like this

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are using ajax invocation to access to your controller. So the String that you are returning is the information that the Ajax post are receiving as response.

I know two ways to make what you want to do:

For both ways, you have to add a method in the controller like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/gDirectory/bhanutest.htm" ,method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String bhanuTest() {
    return "bhanuTest";
}
```

First option (javascript way):

Add a Success callback in your $.post and redirect to "yourapplicationpath/gDirectory/bhanutest.htm"

```
$.post("/gDirectory/bhanutest.htm",{ userIds: userIds, userName: userName }, function(){
   window.location.href = "yourapplicationpath/gDirectory/bhanutest.htm";
});
```

Second option (java way):

Modify your controller and add a "sendRedirect()" method invocation to your HttpServletRequest, like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/gDirectory/bhanutest.htm" ,method=RequestMethod.POST)
public void bhanuTest(@RequestParam String userIds,String userName,Model model, HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("The userId is..:"+userId);
    httpServletResponse.sendRedirect("/gDirectory/bhanutest.htm");
}
```

Another way is to make a classic Post with Html Form, without using Ajax.